# Azure AD authentication to call Office 365 and Graph API REST

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I've created a sample MVC app using VS 2015 and used Azure AD Auth wizard. When I launch this web application, it asked me to register app with Azure AD (first time only) and then userid/password. I have entered Office 365/Azure AD account and successfully logged in. Everything is working perfectly fine and at the top right, I can see Hello "myname".

Now I tried to make REST call to Office 365 using RestSharp. It is giving me `403 error (access denied)`.

When I tried to use graph api url `https://graph.windows.net/testname.com/groups?api-version=1.6`, I am getting error `unauthorized access`.

Here is my test code with graph API call:

```
 string url = "https://graph.windows.net/testname.com/groups?api-version=1.6";
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.ClearHandlers();
            var jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
            client.AddHandler("application/json", jsonDeserializer);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
```

I am using same code  with O365 REST url for Office 365 call.

Why I am getting access denied in both cases if my app is already authenticated against Azure AD which is the base authentication. Also `Request.IsAuthenticated` is always true.

Isn't a single identity provider (AAD) used for Azure, Office 365 and related resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your app isn't configured to call the `/groups` endpoint of graph.  While the end user is authenticated and you have gotten tokens for the Azure AD Graph (`graph.windows.net`), this access token needs to have a certain set of permissions to call the endpoints.

To configure these graph permissions, you can go to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), select *Azure Active Directory*, then *App Registrations*, and finally *Required Permissions*. The resource your calling is *Windows Azure Active Directory* and then you can look through the list of scopes for what you want to call.

Another great resource I'll recommend is the Azure AD Graph Explorer. This can help understand the type of data the graph can provide.

***Edit:*** Checkout comments for answer. OP had used the OpenID Connect middleware (OWIN) and needed help getting an access token for a resource. In order to do this, you must use a combination of OWIN + ADAL. OWIN gets an auth code, and ADAL can exchange this auth code for an access token.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,I have checked all permissions with Azure AD to access Microsoft Graph and Office 365 REST.All are good.Is there any need to reauthorize app with client id and secret? I believe once registered with  Azure AD and default MVC template code provide authentication (Owin) .And that is why I can logged in and see my logged in name at top right

Comment: You shouldn't need to, but go ahead and try this: *Azure Portal* > *Azure AD* > *App Registrations* > *Delegated Permissions* > *Grant Permissions*. This will grant consent to all the permissions for every user in your tenant.  Check one more thing, when you get an acess token drop it into https://www.calebb.net and make sure the resource is `graph.windows.net` and has the right scopes. It's possible your auth request isn't being constructed properly.

Comment: Delegated permissions for all users have been already granted.No issue with permissions.App is using OpenId Connect with Clientid. Is this suffice or I need to do something with client secret as well

Comment: I may have overlooked what you said earlier comment.  To get an access token for Azure AD Graph, you'll have to use both OWIN and ADAL.  OWIN will sign in the user and get an id toke + code, and then you can use ADAL to get the access token for graph (requesting graph as your resource). [Here's a code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) implementing what I'm describing.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks once again . This is what I was trying to understand.Once you get token shouldn't be applicable to call O365,Graph API or others unified APIs

Comment: Thanks Daniel ! Got it